# How to pass PHP $_SESSION value to new page

Tags: php, html

Im trying to figure out how to use a php `$_SESSION` value.  The situation is:

- Main HTML site has an `<iframe>` that loads **products.php**
- Within **products.php** a form submits and saves the two values below:

  $_SESSION["subtotal"] = $_POST['SUBT'];

  $_SESSION["tax"] = $_POST['TAX'];
- These work well I can echo them no problem (within that page)
- This page replaces **products.php** with **confirmation.php**

Once in the confirmation.php I am not able to grab the session values.  I have tried the following:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION["subtotal"] = $_POST['SUBT'];
$_SESSION["tax"] = $_POST['TAX'];

echo $_SESSION["subtotal"];
echo $_SESSION["tax"];
echo $subtotal;
echo $tax;

?>
```

AND

```
$_SESSION["subtotal"] = $subtotal;
$_SESSION["tax"] = $tax;

echo $_SESSION["subtotal"];
echo $_SESSION["tax"];
echo $subtotal;
echo $tax;

?>
```

AND

```
$subtotal = $new_subtotal;
$tax = $new_tax;

echo $new_tax;
echo $new_subtotal;

?>
```

All have failed to see `$_SESSION` - Is the value getting lost with the `<iframe>` change?

I have used the following code on the **products.php** page to confirm the session were susecssfully created - They are:

```
echo $_SESSION["subtotal"]." stored in session <br />";
echo $_SESSION["tax"]." stored in session <br />";
```

**NOTES:**

- Both confirmation & products.php are on the same server.
- print_r($_SESSION); Returns BLANK array.
- session_start() is at the very top of both pages

Comment: are both pages on the same server?

Comment: It gets a bit funky here.  Main html site is on our server.  1st form page sends a token request to PayPal through our server to theirs.  They send request back.  Now when user enters CC info this page (products.php) shoots directly to PayPal with token.  Not sure if that matters.  But confirmation.php & products.php exist on the same server in the same folder. - Hope that helps

Comment: on `confirmation.php` do this:- `<?php
session_start(); echo "<pre/>";print_r($_SESSION);` and check you have  `subtotal` and `tax` indexes in it or not? comment rest of the code for now

Comment: did you start session on `product.php` also?

Comment: Ok I get an empty Array()

Comment: Yes I did start session on products.php

Comment: Yes session is started on both pages

Comment: to set a session cookie you need session_start before any HTML output is produced, else you need to pass the session id manually.

Comment: Yep I def have session_start at the very top of both pages

Comment: iframes very specifically are designed to operate as a separate session from the page loading them and can cause all sorts of problems when you try piecemealing your page together out of them.  They are best reserved for cases when you need to create a widget that needs to run exactly the same on any website, anywhere (like a Google Map or a Youtube Video). Instead of an iframe, you may want to consider using AJAX to submit your form if you are trying to do it without forcing a full page reload.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

products.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['myValue']=$_GET['YourFormElement'];
//or
$_SESSION['myValue']=3; // You can set the value however you like.
?>
```

Any other PHP page:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['myValue'];
?>
```

A few notes to keep in mind though: You need to call session_start() BEFORE any output, HTML, echos - even whitespace.

You can keep changing the value in the session - but it will only be able to be used after the first page - meaning if you set it in page 1, you will not be able to use it until you get to another page or refresh the page.

The setting of the variable itself can be done in one of a number of ways:

```
$_SESSION['myValue']=1;
$_SESSION['myValue']=$var;
$_SESSION['myValue']=$_GET['YourFormElement'];
```

And if you want to check if the variable is set before getting a potential error, use something like this:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['myValue'])
{
    echo $_SESSION['myValue'];
}
else
{
    echo "Session not set yet.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though this is pretty much what I am already doing.  I flopped some of my code out with yours.  No results

Comment: what means no result

Comment: I keep getting a blank array() when I do a simple - print_r($_SESSION);

Comment: yes in new page you assign $_SESSION= $subtotal while $subtotal have no value at new page that is a new variable which is not initialized

Comment: for session you initialized once than by this you can get value at any page.you must know session is an associative array which are stored in your own browser catchy.

Answer (score 0):

I did that once by adding $_SESSION to url inside iframe and in file that is used in iframe I used that $_SESSION by $_GET.

I am not sure 100% but it should work as:

```
$session = $_SESSION['session'];

<iframe src="somePage.php?s=<?php echo $session; ?>"></iframe>
```

somePage.php

```
if(isset($_GET['s'])){
   $session = $_GET['s'];
}
```